# Search value in Next Month Record Pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Given that i have a df like this:

```
    ID                Date Amount
0    a 2014-06-13 12:03:56     13
1    b 2014-06-15 08:11:10     14
2    a 2014-07-02 13:00:01     15
3    b 2014-07-19 16:18:41     22
4    b 2014-08-06 09:39:14     17
5    c 2014-08-22 11:20:56     55
              ...
129  a 2016-11-06 09:39:14     12
130  c 2016-11-22 11:20:56     35
131  b 2016-11-27 09:39:14     42
132  a 2016-12-11 11:20:56     18
```

I need to create a column df['Checking'] to show that ID will appear in next month or not and i tried the code as below:

```
df['Checking']= df.apply(lambda x: check_nextmonth (x.Date, 
                     x.ID), axis=1)
```

where

```
def check_nextmonth(date, id)=
  x= id in df['user_id'][df['Date'].dt.to_period('M')== ((date+ 
              relativedelta(months=1))).to_period('M')].values
  return x
```

but it take too long to process a single row.
How can i improve this code or another way to achieve what i want?

Answer (score 0):

Using `pd.to_datetime` with `ts` tricks:

```
import pandas as pd

df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
df['tmp'] = (df['Date'] - pd.DateOffset(months=1)).dt.month
s = df.groupby('ID').apply(lambda x:x['Date'].dt.month.isin(x['tmp']))
df['Checking'] = s.reset_index(level=0)['Date']
```

Output:

```
  ID                Date  Amount  tmp  Checking
0  a 2014-06-13 12:03:56      13    5      True
1  b 2014-06-15 08:11:10      14    5      True
2  a 2014-07-02 13:00:01      15    6     False
3  b 2014-07-19 16:18:41      16    6      True
4  b 2014-08-06 09:39:14      17    7     False
5  c 2014-08-22 11:20:56      18    7     False
```

Comment: Thanks @Chris ! But what if the date range is more than one year??

Comment: @Jeff Can you explain a bit more? Do you want to check if ID will appear in next _year_?

Comment: The ['tmp'] column only show the month, what if the ['Date'] have multiple years data?

Answer (score 0):

Here's one method of doing it, check if the grouped id's next month is equal to current month + 1, and assign the same by sorting the ID.

```
check = df.groupby('ID').apply(lambda x : x['Date'].dt.month.shift(-1) == x['Date'].dt.month+1).stack().values

df = df.sort_values('ID').assign( checking = check).sort_index()

  ID                Date  Amount  checking
0  a 2014-06-13 12:03:56      13      True
1  b 2014-06-15 08:11:10      14      True
2  a 2014-07-02 13:00:01      15     False
3  b 2014-07-19 16:18:41      16      True
4  b 2014-08-06 09:39:14      17     False
5  c 2014-08-22 11:20:56      18     False
```

Comment: This cannot handle year break (from December to January) where `dt.month` change from 12 to 1 (not 13).